# Python: Using getter or "private" attribute inside setter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, getter-setter, private-members

Suppose I have a class `NamedObject` which has an attribute `name`. Now if I had to use a setter, I would first have to define a getter (I guess?) like so:

```
class NamedObject:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
```

Now I was wondering, inside the setter, should I use `self._name` or `self.name`, the getter or the actual attribute? When setting the name, I ofc. need to use `_name`, but what about when I'm getting INSIDE the setter? For example:

```
@name.setter
def name(self, value):
    if self._name != str(value): # Or should I do 'if self.name != value' ?
        self.doStuff(self._name) # Or doStuff(self.name) ?
        self.doMoreStuff()
        self._name = str(value)
```

Does it actually matter which one to use, and why use one over the other?

Comment: In Python, you usually don't use getters and setters at all.

Comment: Why not? Why do they exist then? O.o every other person I ask tells me to use them, and every other tells me not to.

Comment: @Mahi Use them when you actually have a *reason* to use them - e.g. you want to do something other than just directly assigning and reading the value of an attribute (e.g. validation).

Comment: You usually first just use an instance attribute, then when you believe you have to add some actions/controls for getting/setting you change it to a property, in this way you improve your code in a backward compatible way. Adding random getters/setters that do not do anything is only writing more code, without providing any kind of information hiding or feature.

Comment: @Amber Yeah sorry that was a bad example I came up with there (the main post), but in my actual code I have like 15 lines of code on the setter, and only one on the getter. Should I use getter and setter or not?

Comment: Is this test for inequality in your setter supposed to be an optimization of some kind? I don't think it is saving you anything, and just adding extra code to slow down what would be just a normal assignment.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, as English not being my first language, but the example I gave you on my main post is just an **example**, my actual code is much more complicated than that, and I will either need to use a setter or `setName()` for my purpose, and people told me to use a setter. Then I wasn't sure whether I should use getter or the actual attribute inside my setter?

Comment: @Mahi if you have significant logic in the getter or setter, than it's fine to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your getter has significant logic (like lazy initialization), then you should access through the getter all the time.

```
class Something(object):
    UNINITIALIZED = object()
    LAZY_ATTRS = ('x','y','z')
    def __init__(self):
        for attr in self.LAZY_ATTRS:
            setattr(self, '_'+attr, self.UNINITIALIZED)
    def _get_x(self):
        if self._x is self.UNINITIALIZED:
            self._x = self.doExpensiveInitStuff('x')
        return self._x
```

But if all your getter does is `return self._x`, just access the internal variable directly.

Answer (score 3):

There's no normal reason to use the external interface when your setter is part of the internal interface. I suppose you might be able to construct a scenario where you might want to, but by default, just use the internal variable.

Answer (score 1):

Using the getter instead of just accessing the internal variable adds another function call to your setting logic, and in Python, function calls are expensive. If you are writing this:

```
def _get_x(self):
    return self._x

def _set_x(self, value):
    self._x = value
x = property(fget=_get_x, fset=_set_x)
```

then you are suffering from "Too Much Java" syndrome. Java developers *have* to write this kind of stuff, because if it later becomes necessary to add behavior to the setting or getting of x, all the accesses to x outside of the class have to be recompiled. But in Python, you are far better off keeping things simple, and just defining x as an instance variable, and converting to a property only when the need arises to add some kind of setting or getting behavior. See [YAGNI](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt) and [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it).

Comment: Read my second comment on the main post. I come from C++ side, not Java, but I guess they're pretty much the same. I actually have like 15 lines of code in my setter, I just wrote a quick example for the sake of the question. So this again didn't answer my actual question, but I guess I should blame myself for giving a bad example code :P

Comment: What you have gotten from your simple example is The Conventional Wisdom on using properties in Python: "Don't do it until you need to." If all your getter is doing is `return self._name`, then just access `self._name` in your setter, and avoid an unnecessary function call. If you later need to add behavior to the getter as well and if this behavior is significant from within the setter, you are probably close enough to the setter code to track down the offending direct references to `self._name`.

Answer (score 0):

Paul already answered well.

For the sake of completeness I'd like to add that using getters/setters consistently makes it easier to override a class. There are several implications here.

If you envision that a particular class is very likely to be overriden/extended by yourself or others, then using getters/setters early on might be beneficial in terms of less time spent later for refactoring. Still, I agree to the keep it simple viewpoint: Use the below only sparingly, because of the runtime cost and reading/coding effort.

If validation is done in the getter, too, then either use the instance attribute directly in the setter, or provide two different getters `name()` and `_name()` (or `name_already_checked()`) so that both can be overridden and use the simple getter without validation inside the setter. This is to allow extension of both the fast, no-validation type of getter as well as the usual, provided for customers, getter.

This does violate the YAGNI principle that [Paul pointed to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13443743/923794). However, if you do release code for a wider audience "overengineering" is often advisable. Libraries benefit from added flexibility and foresight.